# Not getting desired result: Package amsmath Error

Tags: math-mode

Quite new to `LaTeX`. I am using TeXStudio 2.10 and the following code producing result I desired.

```
$${\rm{x}} = \left( {\matrix{   {{{\rm{x}}_a}}  \cr    {{{\rm{x}}_b}}  } } \right) $$
```

I need `x_a` and `x_b` in a column whereas it is giving it in row and produces this result

```
Package amsmath Error: Old form `\matrix' should be \begin{matrix}. $${\rm{x}} = \left( {\matrix
```

Thanks

Comment: Oh my, that's old syntax.

Comment: Are you perhaps pasting code built with MathType?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I am very new to LaTex and earlier I used MathType equations as objects in MS Word. For learning purpose I am copying equations in Plain TeX from MathType. Is it a good practice to follow? I have pages of equation, how do people deal with lengthy equations? Kindly let me know. :)  Thanks again

Comment: @pkj : From the product description ( https://www.dessci.com/en/products/MathType/features.htm#export_to_tex ), you can export as "AMS-LaTeX (LaTeX with AMS extensions)", which might be a vastly better way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using (wrong) plain TeX markup in LaTeX, which is classified as *don't-do-it-and-I'm-really-saying-it*.

While plain TeX syntax would accept

```
$$
{\rm x} = \left( \matrix{ {\rm x}_a \cr {\rm x}_b } \right)
$$
```

(I fixed the input, removing useless braces), this is a bad way to go with LaTeX, *especially* if `amsmath` is used:

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{x} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{x}_{a} \\ \mathrm{x}_{b} \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

is the correct input for what you mean to get.

Answer (score 2):

If a `roman`-like font should be used apply `\mathrm{...}` then!

- `$$...$$` is plain TeX syntax, use `\[...\]` instead.
- `\left(\matrix{...}\right)` is `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}` now, the `p` stands for `parenthesis` (i.e. `()`)
- Use `\\` instead of `\cr`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathrm{x} =  \begin{pmatrix}   
  \mathrm{x}_{a}  \\    
  \mathrm{x}_{b}  
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]